# Get OS architecture remotely via PowerShell

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, remote-access

Does anybody know how to grab OS architecture remotely from multiple Windows hosts via PowerShell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem -computer $_ | select-object OSArchitecture`

You'll pipeline the list of computer names into this command so that $_ is interpreted as each computer in your list.

---

Edit: After doing some digging, it appears that this will work on both 2003 and 2008.

`get-wmiobject win32_computersystem -computer $_ | select-object systemtype`

Comment: Perfect, it works great.

Is there a way to grab OS Architecture for 2003 servers the same way?

Comment: Hm, I don't see anything in the `win32_operatingsystem` class properties on 2003 that would work. There might be something in `win32_processor` but I don't have anything handy to test it with.

Comment: MDMarra, this is great! Thx for sharing this, that's really hepful. I've start digging into WMIC to get this info for Windows Server 2003 machines.
Something like 

WMIC /NODE:"TESTSERVER1","TESTSERVER2",@"C:\COMPUTERLIST.TXT"   cpu get DataWidth /format:list

Comment: You know you can run that second PowerShell command against a 2003 machine remotely even if it doesn't have PowerShell installed, right? No need to mess with the voodoo black magic known as wmic :)

Answer (score 2):

For Windows XP/2003 and up, Win32_Processor has an AddressWidth property which will be 32 or 64, as appropriate.

There's 1 WMI object instance of class Win32_Processor for each CPU known to Windows' Device Manager, so I've typically done this sort of thing in the past. It's VBScript, my PowerShell sucks, but you get the idea...

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor WHERE AddressWidth='64'")
If colItems.Count = 0 Then
    strArch = "x86"
Else
    strArch = "x64"
End If
```

**update**: translated to PowerShell:

```
If ($(Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor WHERE AddressWidth='64'")) {
    Write-Host "I'm x64"
} Else {
    Write-Host "I'm x86"
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but the OP asked for PowerShell.

Comment: Fair enough, I figured that was simple enough to be translated to PowerShell by someone who is sufficiently familiar with it. I'm not.

Comment: OK so...... killer Google-fu + a pocket full of common sense = PowerShell version. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little less fancy, but for those who don't have remote WMI enabled, a little old-school way would be:

```
$compList = #<whatever you use to source your list of machines>
ForEach($comp in $compList){
    $testPath64 = '\\' + $comp + '\c$\Program Files (x86)'
    $testPath = '\\' + $comp + '\c$\Program Files'
    $arch = Test-Path $testPath64
    If($arch){Write-Host "$comp is x64"}
    Else{
        $arch = Test-Path $testPath
        If($arch){Write-Host "$comp is x86"}
        Else{Write-Host "No idea..."}
    }
}
```

Or something like that. The crux of the point being, test-path to Program Files (x86) which is only present on 64-bit machines.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
PS > $env:processor_architecture
AMD64
```

[PowerShell 32-bit or 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19796466)